# Which of the two approaches to get max value from all records of object is correct?

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

```
AggregateResult[] resPriceResult = [SELECT MAX(Price__c) max FROM Resource__c];
```

OR

```
List<Resource__c> mpList = [
    SELECT Price__c FROM Resource__c
    WHERE Price__c != null
    ORDER BY Price__c DESC
    LIMIT 1
]
```

First one seems like the correct way of doing this, but if I understand correctly if there is more than 50000 records that are processed by Aggregate Query there will be `LimitException`.

Second approach solves the problem of Limits as it only returns one records with the biggest `Price__c`.

Comment: Hi. Where did you see the 50 000 records limit? I'm interested. I didn't know that.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm - at the bottom there is orangeish block.

Comment: Thanks ! You are right, the second approach seems to be the best to avoid the 50 000 records limit.

Comment: second seem better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have already found the answer: using `LIMIT 1` will avoid hitting `LimitException`. Take a look at [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111535/exception-query-timeout-your-query-request-was-running-for-too-long/111537#111537), however. You may notice better performance if you change your query to:

```
List<Resource__c> mpList = [
    SELECT Price__c FROM Resource__c
    ORDER BY Price__c DESC NULLS LAST
    LIMIT 1
]
```

Take a look at [Working with Very Large SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm). Querying for `field != null` will hurt your performance.

> - Typically, a custom index isn’t used in these cases.
>
>   - The queried values exceed the system-defined threshold.
>   - The filter operator is a negative operator such as NOT EQUAL TO (or !=), NOT CONTAINS, and NOT STARTS WITH.
>   - The CONTAINS operator is used in the filter, and the number of rows to be scanned exceeds 333,333. The CONTAINS operator requires a full scan of the index. This threshold is subject to change.
>   - **You’re comparing with an empty value (Name != '').**

Answer (score 1):

True answer to that question would be "**depend on your data set**".

If you know for sure that you have less than 50 k rows first query returns result faster. Also its more readable so other developers will understand it by just glancing at it.

If you are not sure about your data set then second approach will be appropriate.

Here is profiling screen shot that shows 1st approach is faster.

[image]

PS: if you are not aware about about how to use profiling then take a look at this page https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Guide_to_Application_Performance_Profiling_in_Force.com

**Edit 1:**

The other options could be store this max value in custom setting and refer it directly from there in your code without any SOQL.

You will need to write a trigger on Resource__c to see if new value of Price__c is greater than custom setting then update custom setting.

You will also need to consider race condition depending on your data set.  But in some situation this would fit best.

Comment: OP at least strongly implies >50K records, and even if not, this will waste a lot of query rows from your governor limit when you only need to consume one.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going with:

`List<Resource__c> mpList = [SELECT Price__c FROM Resource__c ORDER BY Price__c DESC LIMIT 1]`

If you go with your first option then each row that exists for Resource__c will count against your [SOQL records governor limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). This means that if you had 40k rows then you'd use up 40k out of 50k record limit for the execution cycle.

**FYI:** If you need to filter on your custom Price__c field then setting it as an External Id will cause it to be indexed by Salesforce.